# How can I make a short connection with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the url

*www.example.com/hy7fj.php*

and I want to rewrite it as:

*www.example.com/hy7fj*

How can I make a short connection with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly get what do You mean with "short connection with .htaccess" but you can add the next lines to it and see if it is what you were looking for:

**RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^hy7fj/ hy7fj.php**

First line allows the server to rewrite urls
Second one  tell the server to "load" hy7fj.php when /hy7fj is accessed.